# Windows 10 build is about to expire on 7/31/2020 - Click more info on dialog, but page doesn't exist

Tags: windows-10, upgrade

I keep getting the windows 10 message that my build is about to expire. I click on the more info button but it hits to a page is not found on microsoft. What do I do now?

It's a licensed windows on my laptop from thinkpad. I just opted in to try one of the newer builds awhile back. I'm not sure what to do now. Also do I need to login as administrator to deal with this?

Comment: where and how do i do that ?

Comment: Go to Start, Settings, Update and scroll down for Windows Insider. See where you are in the program and if you wish to proceed.  I agree with the above and suggest you update. Current Insider version is 2004 Build 20175.1000.

Comment: I took the Version and Build directly from the most current insider build, so the information is correct. 21H1 is another designation. There does not seem to be a more current update at this point.